# Replace table with div using display: table

Tags: html, html-table

Can I completely rewrite `<table>` to `<div>` using the display property.

I've tried with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2PbSe/, but it does not use a 100% width?

Comment: But what sense does it make? Using tables to create a page layout is a bad thing but using tables to display tables is the best choice to do. This seems like you want to emulate a real table with some divs. That's not a good idea.

Comment: I just need to group columns and rows more than html tables allow me if it has to be valid, so I thought it was smart to do with divs

Comment: To merge columns you can do <td colspan="5"> to merge rows: <td rowspan="5"> to group rows you can use <tfoot> <tbody> and <thead>. You can use multiple tbody-s to group your rows. You also have a <caption> and <colgroup> to play with. And all of these are "standard" solutions while your div-s in this case are kinda "hacky", I think.

Comment: You can try this link:-https://html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for. But your example has a nesting problem with the `class="body"` element. Removing it should get a more "true" representation of a `<table>`. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wn0v50mp/1/). If you set the width of the root element to 100% it will grow to the width of the containing element.